# How to open target blank in a custom admin sub menu page?

Tags: wordpress

Here is my external link menu function for admin area:

```
##CACHE MENU
add_action('admin_menu', 'mariCacheDel');
function mariCacheDel() {
    global $submenu;
    $url = get_bloginfo('wpurl').'/cache/?do=deleteAll';
    $submenu['themes.php'][] = array('MARIA CACHE', 'manage_options', $url);
}
```

How can we open a `_blank` browser window with this link?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has to be with jQuery and using a small trick in the `admin_menu` to insert a target div with an ID:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'mariCacheDel');
function mariCacheDel() {
    global $submenu;
    $submenu['themes.php'][] = array(
            '<div id="maricache">MARIA CACHE</div>', // <-- trick
            'manage_options', 
            site_url( '/cache/?do=deleteAll' )
    );
}

add_action( 'admin_footer', 'make_maricache_blank' );    
function make_maricache_blank()
{
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#maricache').parent().attr('target','_blank');
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: jejeje, yes, I like this trick :) I tried some pretty bizarre jQuery selectors before realizing we can add some specific HTML in the menu and bingo! . . .  Note that [**`get_bloginfo()`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo) is not the best function to use in many cases.